# Git checkout updates local branch and remote repository at the same time

Tags: git, repository, git-checkout

I have a local repository with 3 branches - *main, major-test, recovery* - and a remote repository with equivalent branches - *main, major-test, recovery*. My current working branch is *major-test*.
During an attempt to revert a bad commit, I used a series of *git reset* and *git revert*. In the end, I realised that I made a mess and to fix it I moved the 'myfile.java' file with the correct changes to a different branch *recovery*. Now, I wanted to retrieve the 'myfile.java' file saved in the recovery branch and update the current branch, *major-test*, with those changes. So, I used the following command:

> git checkout recovery -- src/myfile.java

It worked as expected and the current working folder src contains the 'myfile.java' file with the changes I wanted. However, what I did not expect was that also my remote repository got updated at the same time. Usually, when I want that some changes on my local repository are reflected on the remote (called origin) I use this command:

> git push -u origin major_test:major_test

This time it was not necessary and I don't understand why.Indeed, I logged in into the webpage of my github repository and noticed that the file there was the one with the updated version.
It also means that when I check the status with the 'git status' command I get this:

> On branch major_test
>
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/major_test'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

Is it possible that during the previous attempt to fix a bad commit I accidentally pushed the changes into the remote repository but those changes were not visible because they were not synchronised with the local repo?

Comment: I am not completely sure that the remote was changed when you did the checkout (actually, quite the opposite, bus alas). How did you come to that conclusion? I mean, what command did you run and the output. Can you specify that in the question?

Comment: It's impossible for a local checkout operation to have an effect on a different clone of the same repository on a different host. Check the commits of your remote repository and it will tell you which commit changed the file.